# Ler dados de uma celula do Excel para busca via SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, powerquery

Preciso executar um SQL que me traga um resultado de apenas uma célula, mas, preciso capturar informação de duas.

Vou entrar com data inicial e data final, meu resultado vai ser um valor calculado nesse prazo.

Já tentei várias formas que encontrei, mas não sei se eu não soube aplicar ou não deram certo pro meu caso.

O SQL de consulta:

```
select sum(cr.vl_receber)
  from contareceber cr
 where cr.dt_vencimento >= '20/12/2019'
   and cr.dt_vencimento <= '26/12/2019'
   and cr.cd_empresa = 1
   and cr.cd_filial in (1,5)
   and cr.cd_pessoa not in (4, 5, 8)
   and cr.cd_formapgto = 3
   and cr.tp_status in ('AB','IP','CA','PR','CO','IN')
```

As datas eu preciso ler de uma célula da Planilha e depois o usuário vai apenas atualizar as datas nessa célula, para que não precise atualizar no script.

Ou seja, o usuário atualizar a data na tabela do excel e o script já pegar a data, carregar e exibir o resultado esperado.

Imagino que algo utilizado através do PowerQuery ajudaria, mas tentei códigos do tipo:

```
cr.dt_vencimento >= '"=Planilha1!B8"'
cr.dt_vencimento <= '"=Planilha1!C8"'
```

ou:

```
cr.dt_vencimento >= '"B8"'
cr.dt_vencimento <= '"C8"'
```

ou:

```
cr.dt_vencimento >= '"& B8 &"'
cr.dt_vencimento <= '"& C8 &"'
```

Enfim, não consegui ou não soube utilizar.
Como posso fazer essa consulta dessa celula e carregar no script para que a consulta fique mais simples para o usuário?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para concatenar esse tipo de informação é necessário utilizar o vba:

```
Sub Download_Standard_BOM()
'Inicializando variaveis
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

'Conectando com o banco de dados SQL
   'Insira as informações corretas:
       '1: PASSWORD
       '2: USERNAME
       '3: REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS
       '4: DATABASE
    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=PASSWORD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Data Source=REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DATABASE"

    'Abrindo conexção
    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    'Definir limite para erro de timeout
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    'Consulta do SQL
    StrQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tbl_table"

    'Executando consulta
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    'Inserindo o resultado da consulta na primeira aba celula A2
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub
```

Com isso você poderá executar qualquer tipo de consulta concatenando campos do excel e inserir os resultados em uma célula.

Não se esqueça de habilitar na bibliotica do vba a opção:

**ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library**

Crie um botão e inclua a macro.

Obs.: Na consulta SQL crie seu select e concatene as informações como seu último exemplo:

```
...'"& B8 &"'...
```